# Sequence of Bernouilli trials with diminishing returns

Tags: distributions, model, exponential-family

Say I have a sequence of yes-no trials where the probability of winning decays over time **as the supply of wins is gradually exhausted**. Assume that for every trial the probability of replacement is **not 1 nor 0**, but some other value.

Are there any known distributions that model this behavior?

Comment: The [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)? Though the supply of failures gets exhausted too, so the probability of winning could go up or down depending on the results of earlier trials.

Comment: Great pointer @Scortchi - Thanks! What if I have **some** rate of replacement? It looks like the hypergeometric distribution assumes **no** replacement, and the binomial assumes **replacement**, e.g. with a probability of replacement = `q`

Comment: You'd perhaps be able to look at it as something along the lines of an Urn model. In any case, it's likely to be complicated, but you should be able to work out an asymptotic normal approximation, and simulation from the process would be straightforward.

Comment: For an answer more specific than what is already in coments, you will need to specify the model better ...